# Expected value of maximum of a matrix of size $n$

Tags: probability-theory, matrices

I have a square matrix (call it $A$) of size $n$ ($n$ is a positive integer). Each column is a permutation of $[1:n]$.

I take the first row of $A$, i.e. $A(1,:)$ and wonder what will be the frequency of the mode. This is, how many times the most common element in the first row of $A$ will appear and whether the mode will be unique.

For example, if

```
A=
 1     2     5     4     1
 3     3     3     1     3
 5     5     2     2     5
 2     1     4     5     4
 4     4     1     3     2
```

Then the frequency of the mode is 2 (because 1 appears two times), and the mode is unique because the second most common element in $A(1,:)$ only appears once.

Simulations have shown me that if $n=100$, then the frequency of the mode is 4.23 and is unique in 51% of the cases.

If $n=500$, then the frequency of the mode is $5.14$ and is unique in 47% of the cases.

Any help understanding how these two numbers depend on $n$ would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the permutations distinct?

Comment: Unless there are special (untold) constraints, there is no need to consider a matrix of permutations. What you have is just a uniform distribution.

Comment: It is easy to find examples with a non-unique mode. (In particular, if all elements are distinct, they are all modes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classical [balls into bins problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_into_bins_problem) with as many balls as bins. The maximum load is with high probability about $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is the probability that the maximum load is unique known?

Comment: Why not try and look it up, now that you know what's it called?